# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: current should be >= start and <= end

Tags: android, datepicker

I am trying to implement date picker on a button in android. But as soon as i click on the button error pops up. But time picker runs fine. Here's the code:

```
mPickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {       //Assigning onClickListener to Date Button                                                                  
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
            }    
    });

    pickTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {        //Assigning onClickListener to Time Button

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(TIME_DIALOG_ID);

        }
    });
    }

    @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {                       //Overriding onCreateDialog()
        switch (id) {
        case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
            return new TimePickerDialog(this,mTimeSetListener,mHour,mMin,true);

        }
        return null;
    }

    TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener mTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {        //Defining the TimePickerDialog reference variable

        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {
            mHour=hourOfDay;
            mMin= minute;
            updateTime();
        }
    };

    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListener =                       //Defining the DatePickerDialog reference variable
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, 
                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                mYear = year;
                mMonth = monthOfYear;
                mDay = dayOfMonth;
                updateDisplay();
            }
        };
```

Here's the logcat:

```
10-13 16:41:46.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(761): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-13 16:41:46.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(761): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: current should be >= start and <= end
10-13 16:41:46.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(761):     at android.widget.NumberPicker.setCurrent(NumberPicker.java:288)
10-13 16:41:46.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(761):     at android.widget.DatePicker.updateDaySpinner(DatePicker.java:370)
10-13 16:41:46.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(761):     at android.widget.DatePicker.updateSpinners(DatePicker.java:356)
10-13 16:41:46.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(761):     at android.widget.DatePicker.init(DatePicker.java:352)
10-13 16:41:46.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(761):     at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:127)
10-13 16:41:46.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(761):     at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:86)
10-13 16:41:46.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(761):     at acb.xiynove.OfflineScreen_ACBActivity.onCreateDialog(OfflineScreen_ACBActivity.java:74)
10-13 16:41:46.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(761):     at android.app.Activity.onCreateDialog(Activity.java:2482)
10-13 16:41:46.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(761):     at android.app.Activity.createDialog(Activity.java:882)
10-13 16:41:46.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(761):     at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2557)
10-13 16:41:46.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(761):     at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2524)
10-13 16:41:46.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(761):     at acb.xiynove.OfflineScreen_ACBActivity$3.onClick(OfflineScreen_ACBActivity.java:56)
10-13 16:41:46.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(761):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
10-13 16:41:46.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(761):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
10-13 16:41:46.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(761):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
10-13 16:41:46.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(761):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-13 16:41:46.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(761):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-13 16:41:46.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(761):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
10-13 16:41:46.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(761):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-13 16:41:46.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(761):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-13 16:41:46.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(761):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-13 16:41:46.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(761):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-13 16:41:46.878: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(761):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I've got the same problem but I found solution. You should initialize **mYear,mMonth,mDay**:

```
//Init this variables as you wish eg.:
private int mYear = 2010;
private int mMonth = 11;
private int mDay =1;
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {                       //Overriding onCreateDialog()
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    case TIME_DIALOG_ID:
        return new TimePickerDialog(this,mTimeSetListener,mHour,mMin,true);

    }
    return null;
}
```