# DatePicker Not working, IllegalArgumentException

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I'm using API level 10, I don't want to use support libraries only to implement DatePicker so I'm using the following approach to create a Date Dialog. I've used a single DatePicker before and it worked fine. I'm just unable to see what's the problem here.

I have two date dialogs to select date from which are called upon by individual OnClickListeners. Could anyone please help? Thank you.

// This is in onCreate

```
 ImageView fromCalendar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.from_calendar);
ImageView toCalendar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.to_calendar);


fromCalendar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        showDialog(FROM_DATE_DIALOG);

    }
});

toCalendar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        showDialog(TO_DATE_DIALOG);

    }
});


 private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener toDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {

        mYear = year;
        mMonth = monthOfYear;
        mDay = dayOfMonth;
        Log.e("mYear", "" + year + " mMonth:" + mMonth + " mDay" + mDay);
        String date = updateDisplay(true);

        toDate.setText(date);
    }
};
```

//outside onCreate

```
private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener fromDateSetListener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {

        mYear = year;
        mMonth = monthOfYear;
        mDay = dayOfMonth;
        Log.e("mYear", "" + year + " mMonth:" + mMonth + " mDay" + mDay);
        String date = updateDisplay(true);

        fromDate.setText(date);
    }
};



protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch(id) {

    case FROM_DATE_DIALOG:
        Log.e("onCreateDialog::mYear", "" + mYear + " mMonth:" + mMonth
                + " mDay" + mDay);
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, fromDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth,
                mDay);


    case TO_DATE_DIALOG:
        Log.e("onCreateDialog::mYear", "" + mYear + " mMonth:" + mMonth
                + " mDay" + mDay);
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, toDateSetListener, mYear, mMonth,
                mDay);
    }
    return null; 
}
```

Comment: Please provide your logcat output

Comment: where `mYear ,mMonth,mDay` get initialized ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, It's a duplicate!

[java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: current should be >= start and <= end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753309/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-current-should-be-start-and-end)

I just had to initialize mYear, mMonth and mDay.