# DatePicker crashing with NullPointerException

Tags: android, datepicker

Currently i applied a `DatePicker` into my application and when i click the `Button`, it crashed. Below is the logcat:

```
08-18 00:22:39.564: E/AndroidRuntime(793): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-18 00:22:39.564: E/AndroidRuntime(793): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity  ComponentInfo{com.stts.sparetimetradingsystem/com.stts.sparetimetradingsystem.employer.EditEventActivity}:  java.lang.NullPointerException
08-18 00:22:39.564: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
08-18 00:22:39.564: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
08-18 00:22:39.564: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-18 00:22:39.564: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-18 00:22:39.564: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-18 00:22:39.564: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-18 00:22:39.564: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-18 00:22:39.564: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-18 00:22:39.564: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-18 00:22:39.564: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-18 00:22:39.564: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-18 00:22:39.564: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-18 00:22:39.564: E/AndroidRuntime(793): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-18 00:22:39.564: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at com.stts.sparetimetradingsystem.employer.EditEventActivity.updateDisplayFrom(EditEventActivity.java:532)
08-18 00:22:39.564: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at com.stts.sparetimetradingsystem.employer.EditEventActivity.onCreate(EditEventActivity.java:236)
08-18 00:22:39.564: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-18 00:22:39.564: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
08-18 00:22:39.564: E/AndroidRuntime(793):  ... 11 more
```

Sorry for not placing my code. Here is my code:

```
private int mYear;
private int mMonth;
private int mDay;
static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_event);

    edit_eventSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.edit_spinner);
    btnSaveEvent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSaveEvent);
    btnDeleteEvent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDeleteEvent);
    edit_error = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_error);

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this, R.array.salary_array,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    edit_eventSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    edit_eventSpinner
            .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                        View view, int position, long id) {

                    if (position == 0) {
                        rate = "/hour";
                    } else if (position == 1) {
                        rate = "/day";
                    } else {
                        rate = "/month";
                    }
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });

    // getting event details from intent
    Intent i = getIntent();

    // getting event id (EID) from intent
    eid = i.getStringExtra(TAG_EID);

    // Getting complete event details in background thread
    new GetEventDetails().execute();

    // save button click event
    btnSaveEvent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // starting background task to update event
            String e = edit_eventName.getText().toString();
            String c = edit_eventCName.getText().toString();
            String s = edit_eventSalary.getText().toString();
            String f = edit_eventFrom.getText().toString();
            String t = edit_eventTo.getText().toString();
            String whf = edit_eventWHFrom.getText().toString();
            String wht = edit_eventWHTo.getText().toString();
    });

    // Delete button click event
    btnDeleteEvent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // deleting event in background thread
            new DeleteEvent().execute();
        }
    });

    Button edit_pickDateFrom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.edit_pickDateFrom);

    edit_pickDateFrom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });

    updateDisplayFrom();
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {

    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, mDateSetListenerFrom, mYear,
                mMonth, mDay);
    }
    return null;
}

protected void onPrepareDialog(int id, Dialog dialog) {
    switch (id) {

    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        ((DatePickerDialog) dialog).updateDate(mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        break;
    }

}

// SET THE DATE FORMAT ALREADY USER SELECT FROM THE DATEPICKER
private void updateDisplayFrom() {
    edit_eventFrom.setText(new StringBuilder()
            // Month is 0 based so add 1
            .append(mDay).append("-").append(mMonth + 1).append("-")
            .append(mYear).append(""));
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener mDateSetListenerFrom = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
            int dayOfMonth) {
        mYear = year;
        mMonth = monthOfYear;
        mDay = dayOfMonth;
        updateDisplayFrom();
    }
};
```

Below is the new error that i get after even though i initialized the edit_eventName etc.

```
08-18 01:09:56.764: E/AndroidRuntime(977): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-18 01:09:56.764: E/AndroidRuntime(977): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: current should be >= start and <= end
08-18 01:09:56.764: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at android.widget.NumberPicker.setCurrent(NumberPicker.java:288)
08-18 01:09:56.764: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at android.widget.DatePicker.updateDaySpinner(DatePicker.java:364)
08-18 01:09:56.764: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at android.widget.DatePicker.updateSpinners(DatePicker.java:350)
08-18 01:09:56.764: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at android.widget.DatePicker.init(DatePicker.java:346)
08-18 01:09:56.764: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:124)
08-18 01:09:56.764: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at android.app.DatePickerDialog.<init>(DatePickerDialog.java:83)
08-18 01:09:56.764: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at com.stts.sparetimetradingsystem.employer.EditEventActivity.onCreateDialog(EditEventActivity.java:527)
08-18 01:09:56.764: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at android.app.Activity.onCreateDialog(Activity.java:2472)
08-18 01:09:56.764: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at android.app.Activity.createDialog(Activity.java:881)
08-18 01:09:56.764: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2547)
08-18 01:09:56.764: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at android.app.Activity.showDialog(Activity.java:2514)
08-18 01:09:56.764: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at com.stts.sparetimetradingsystem.employer.EditEventActivity$5.onClick(EditEventActivity.java:245)
08-18 01:09:56.764: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
08-18 01:09:56.764: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
08-18 01:09:56.764: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-18 01:09:56.764: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-18 01:09:56.764: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-18 01:09:56.764: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-18 01:09:56.764: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-18 01:09:56.764: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-18 01:09:56.764: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-18 01:09:56.764: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-18 01:09:56.764: E/AndroidRuntime(977):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post EditEventActivity.java:532 and surrounding code/

Comment: You need to attach the code for us to help you.

Comment: In line 532 of EditEventActivity.java, you're accessing a null reference.

Comment: I think you forgot to inflate your datePicker. We need the code near line 532.

Comment: i have uploaded my code please have a look and teach me where is my error. thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as though you have not initialized `edit_eventFrom` anywhere in the code you posted.

You will need to inflate that `View` from your layout, like you did your other `Views`:

```
edit_eventSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.edit_spinner);
btnSaveEvent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSaveEvent);
btnDeleteEvent = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDeleteEvent);
edit_error = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.edit_error);
```

And as *swayam* mentioned, you will need to do this for any `View` you are wanting to use in your code.

> *swayam*
>
> Similarly, initialize all the following EditText views before using in your code

---

**Second Error**

> IllegalArgumentException: current should be >= start and <= end

You need to initialize `mYear`, `mDay` and `mMonth` to some default or whatever value you want.

[Reference for this solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7753309/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-current-should-be-start-and-end)

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the **initialization** of the EditText views with reference to your XML.

```
EditText edit_eventName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.idOfThisEditTextInYourXML);
EditText edit_eventFrom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.idOfThisEditTextInYourXML);
```

Similarly, initialize all the following EditText views before using in your code :

```
            edit_eventCName
            edit_eventSalary
            edit_eventFrom
            edit_eventTo
            edit_eventWHFrom
            edit_eventWHTo
```

You are also missing the **initializations** for `mDay, mMonth and mYear`. You need to assign some values(integers) to them.

```
private int mYear = 2012; // example value
private int mMonth = 7; // example value
private int mDay =17; // example value
```

Comment: I initialize already but still crashed when i click on the datepicker button

Comment: 532 is the space above protected void onPrepareDialog

Comment: You are missing further initializations. Check my updated answer.

Comment: because when user set a date, the code will append day,month,year. then will store as 1 data into my database. so got any idea how i can seperate them into individual data and store as mYear, mDay and mMonth? why i dont want static them is because this is a edit activity.

Comment: If are asking how to store data in the database, I suggest you post it as a separate question. And as far as the DatePicker is concerned, is the application working now ? After the initializations ?

Comment: Its working! thanks alot swayam! It didnt affect my data retrieve from database.

Comment: You are most welcome. I am glad that it got working for you. Good luck. And don't forget to accept the answer that was most helpful. :)